# postman check value in hash in array of array

Tags: javascript, postman

Is there an easy way to check in postman that an array contains a hash where a specific key must have a particular value, like pythons in list.keys():

Static it is fine:

```
pm.test("Schema has userName", function () {
    var rpos = 0;
    var apos = 18;
    pm.expect(jsonData.Resources[rpos].attributes[apos].name).to.eql("userName");
});
```

But when position in Resources and Attributes arrays both can be anywhere:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var rpos = undefined;
var apos = undefined;
var msg = "not found";
for (var i=0; i<jsonData.Resources.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<jsonData.Resources[i].attributes.length; j++) {
        for (key in jsonData.Resources[i].attributes[j]) {
            if (key == "name" && jsonData.Resources[0].attributes[j][key] == 'userName' ) {
                rpos = i;
                apos = j;
                msg = "jsonData.Resources[" + rpos + "].attributes[" + apos + "]['" + key + "']";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
pm.test("Schema has userName (" + msg + ")", function () {
    if(rpos != undefined || apos != undefined) {
        pm.expect(true);
    }
    else {
        pm.expect.fail(false);
    }
});
```

I usually use python and the same test is just a few lines:

```
def username_in_schema():
    if 'Resources' in jsonData.keys():
        for res jsonData['Resources']:
            if 'name' in res['attributes'].keys():
                if res['attributes']['name'] == 'userName':
                    return True
    return False
```